# Trying to draw multiple scatterplot in one graph based on core data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to graph multiple plot in one graph. When I know how many plot I want to graph, I can doit. The problem arise when I need to graph many plot based on core data entity.For example, if the core data entity has 5 count, then I need to draw 5 plots in one graph.
I've successfully set up the plot, as you can see in the picture.

[image: coreplot scatterplot]

This is the setup code for the scatter plot and data

```
-(void)renderInLayer:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(10,150,300,250);
    FESubView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:frame1];
    FESubView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:FESubView];


#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    CGRect bounds = layerHostingView.bounds;
#else
    CGRect bounds = NSRectToCGRect(layerHostingView.bounds);
#endif

    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
    FESubView.hostedGraph = graph;
    graph.title = @"Fuel Economy Graph";
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 14.0f;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);

    // 4 - Set padding for plot area
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:40.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:65.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingTop:3.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingRight:3.0f];

    // Setup scatter plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0.0f;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay * 10)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10.0f)];

    //symbol

    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1)];

    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

    // Create a plot that uses the data source method
    CPTMutableTextStyle *feLabelStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    feLabelStyle.fontSize = 10;
    feLabelStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

    NSArray *cptColors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[CPTColor blueColor],[CPTColor yellowColor],[CPTColor greenColor],[CPTColor orangeColor],[CPTColor whiteColor], nil];
    [self fetchVehicleModel];


    int counts = [self.fullVehicleData count];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < counts; i++)
    {
        CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
        dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] objectAtIndex:i];
       CPTColor *feColor = cptColors[i];
        CPTMutableLineStyle *feLineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        feLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
        feLineStyle.lineColor = feColor;
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = feLineStyle;
       CPTMutableLineStyle *feSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        feSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = feColor;
        CPTPlotSymbol *feSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
        feSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:feColor];
        feSymbol.lineStyle = feSymbolLineStyle;
        feSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
        dataSourceLinePlot.plotSymbol = feSymbol;
        //CPTTextStyle *test = [CPTTextStyle textStyle];
        //test.fontSize = 12;
        CPTMutableTextStyle *feLabelStyle1 = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        feLabelStyle1.fontSize = 10;
        feLabelStyle1.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        dataSourceLinePlot.labelTextStyle = feLabelStyle;
        //    
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        dataSourceLinePlot.title = [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] objectAtIndex:i];

        [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
        CPTColor *areaColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3
                                                        green:1.0 + i
                                                         blue:0.3
                                                        alpha:0.3];
        CPTGradient *areaGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor
                                                                endingColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
        areaGradient.angle = -90.0f;
        CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient];
        dataSourceLinePlot.areaFill = areaGradientFill;
        dataSourceLinePlot.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1.75");
        CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
        axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        axisTextStyle.fontSize = 8.0f;

        // Axes
        CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
        CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
        x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
        x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");
        x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
        x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;

        dateFormatter = [self setDateFormatter];
        CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
        timeFormatter.referenceDate = _refDate;

        x.labelFormatter            = timeFormatter;
        x.labelRotation            = M_PI / 4;
        x.tickLabelDirection = CPTSignPositive;
        x.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
        x.labelOffset = -50;

        CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
        y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5.0");
        y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 10;
        y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");


        graph.legend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
        graph.legend.borderLineStyle = x.axisLineStyle;
        graph.legend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor darkGrayColor]];
        graph.legend.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        graph.legend.swatchSize = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
        graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;
        graph.legend.textStyle = axisTextStyle;
        graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(2.40, 8.0);
    }
}
```

This is for generating data:

```
-(void)generateData
{

    if ( !plotData ) {

        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit     ) fromDate:[[self.fullTransaction valueForKey:@"tDate" ] objectAtIndex:0]];
        _refDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

        NSDate *dataDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

        NSDateComponents *comps;

        int days;

        // Add some data
        NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];
       // NSMutableArray *newData1 = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSUInteger i;
        NSArray *array1 = nil;
        NSMutableArray *carArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
        //NSUInteger
                NSLog(@"model count is: %lu",(unsigned long)[[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] count]);
        for (int vecCount = 0; vecCount < [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] count]; vecCount ++)
        {
            NSString *make = [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vMake"] objectAtIndex:vecCount];
            NSString *model = [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] objectAtIndex:vecCount];
            NSArray *array = [self filterArraybyMake:make andWithModel:model];

            [carArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
            NSLog(@"car Array are: %@",carArray);
            //}

        }

        for ( i = 0; i < [[self.fullTransaction valueForKey:@"tDate"]count]; i++ )
        {
            //Calculate days difference between dataDate and RefDate
            dataDate = [[self.fullTransaction valueForKey:@"tDate"]objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"RefDate is: %@",_refDate);
            NSLog(@"DateDate is: %@",dataDate);
            comps = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:_refDate toDate:dataDate  options:0];
            days = [comps day] + 1;

            NSTimeInterval x = oneDay *days;

            int counts = [carArray count];
            id y;
            //id z;

            if (i < counts)
            {
                y = [[carArray valueForKey:@"tFuelEconomy" ] objectAtIndex:i];
            }
            else
                y = NULL;

           [newData addObject:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldX],
              y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldY],
              nil]];
        }
        plotData = newData;
        newData = nil;
    }
}
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    switch (fieldEnum)
    {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
        {
            NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
            return num;
        }
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
        {
            NSLog(@"Plot identifier = %@",plot.identifier);
            int identifier = 0;
            for (identifier =0;identifier < [self.fullVehicleData count];identifier ++)
            {
                NSLog(@"identifier from coredata is: %@",[[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"]objectAtIndex:identifier]);
                if ([plot.identifier isEqual:[[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"]objectAtIndex:identifier]])
                {
                    NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
                    NSLog(@"num is %@",num);
                    return num;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return nil;
}
```

Problems:
For this core plot, based on the core data entity has 2 counts. That's why I need to 2 plots in the graph, if you  see the legend of the plot, it seems that I have successfully prepare for 2 plots.

Problem is, when I do checking for the `identifier`, in the `-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index`, I always got the second `plot.identifier` value. How to fix this?

UPDATE ****

I've change the code to the following and it produced the graph as below:

[image: Core Plot after revise]

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    switch (fieldEnum)
    {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
        {
            NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
            return num;
        }
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
        {
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:[[self.fullTransaction valueForKeyPath:@"toVehicle.vModel"]objectAtIndex:index]])
                {
                    NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
                    NSLog(@"num is %@",num);
                    return num;
                }

        }

    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here's the nslog data, it shows that the index is not skipped, and it's not returning null. So I'm really confused.

```
2014-04-01 15:46:04.334 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Jazz 1.5 L
2014-04-01 15:46:04.335 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.335 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 2
2014-04-01 15:46:04.335 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Jazz 1.5 L is 10.58 with date: 2014-03-21 10:20:12 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.336 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.336 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Jazz 1.5 L
2014-04-01 15:46:04.336 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.337 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 3
2014-04-01 15:46:04.337 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Jazz 1.5 L is 11.11 with date: 2014-03-24 11:42:27 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.337 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.338 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Jazz 1.5 L
2014-04-01 15:46:04.338 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.338 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 4
2014-04-01 15:46:04.339 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Jazz 1.5 L is 11.62 with date: 2014-03-28 03:10:59 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.339 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.339 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Jazz 1.5 L
2014-04-01 15:46:04.339 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.340 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 5
2014-04-01 15:46:04.340 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Jazz 1.5 L is <null> with date: 2014-04-01 08:07:05 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.340 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.341 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Jazz 1.5 L
2014-04-01 15:46:04.341 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.341 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 6
2014-04-01 15:46:04.342 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Jazz 1.5 L is 8.59 with date: 2014-04-01 08:31:17 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.342 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.343 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Grand Livina HWS
2014-04-01 15:46:04.343 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.343 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 0
2014-04-01 15:46:04.344 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Grand Livina HWS is 11.43 with date: 2014-03-24 15:33:36 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.344 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.345 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Plot Identifier is: Grand Livina HWS
2014-04-01 15:46:04.345 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Entered Plot
2014-04-01 15:46:04.345 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Index is: 1
2014-04-01 15:46:04.345 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Return data for plot identifier: Grand Livina HWS is 12.5 with date: 2014-03-25 15:29:28 +0000
2014-04-01 15:46:04.346 Fuel Eco[4884:60b] Exit Plot
```

Update 2

this is the updated version,where I get the X value, basically it's contains the difference days between dates.

```
-(void)generateData
{

    if ( !plotData ) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tDate" ascending:YES];
        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[[[self.fullTransaction sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortByDate]]valueForKey:@"tDate"]objectAtIndex:0]];
        _refDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

        NSDate *dataDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

        NSDateComponents *comps;

        int days;

        // Add some data
        NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];

        for ( int i = 0; i < [[self.fullTransaction valueForKey:@"tDate"]count]; i++ )
        {
            //Calculate days difference between dataDate and RefDate
            dataDate = [[self.fullTransaction valueForKey:@"tDate"]objectAtIndex:i];
            comps = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:_refDate toDate:dataDate  options:0];
            days = [comps day] + 1;

            NSTimeInterval x = oneDay *days;

            [newData addObject:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldX],
              nil]];
        }
        plotData = newData;
        newData = nil;
    }
}
```

And this is the revised version of numberofplots

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:[[self.fullTransaction valueForKeyPath:@"toVehicle.vModel"]objectAtIndex:index]])
    {

        switch (fieldEnum)
        {
            case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            {
                NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithLong:fieldEnum]];
                return num;
            }
            case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            {
                    return [[self.fullTransaction valueForKey:@"tFuelEconomy"]objectAtIndex:index];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Regards,

Comment: How is `plotData` used in `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:`? It looks like it only holds data for the last plot.

Comment: Unrelated to the plot issue, but you can move the axis and legend setup code outside the plot setup loop. It only needs to be done once.

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, Yes, you're right. the axis and legend setup code should be outside the plot setup loop. I did change it to inside loop, in desperate move. ^_^. Anyway, for -numberOfRecordsForPlot it only contain one line. return [plotData count];

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, correct me if I'm wrong, my assumption is that, if I want to draw with the same x axis data, then I just return one count.

Comment: HI @EricSkroch, in this line of code:`or (int vecCount = 0; vecCount < [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] count]; vecCount ++)
        {
            NSString *make = [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vMake"] objectAtIndex:vecCount];
            NSString *model = [[self.fullVehicleData valueForKey:@"vModel"] objectAtIndex:vecCount];
            NSArray *array = [self filterArraybyMake:make andWithModel:model];
            
            [carArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
            NSLog(@"car Array are: %@",carArray);
            //}
           
        }
`

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, the above code, contains all data. Not just last plot. Since I use the valueForKey:@"vModel" as plot.identifier ( "Grand Livina HWS", "Jazz 1.5 L"). One thing, I'm confused was when checking plot.identifier always point to the last plot identifier ("Jazz 1.5 L") in the -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index. Did my assumptions wrong? or where should I proceed?

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, I change some code in the numberForPlot: plot Field: like above, the data in dot are presented correctly, the problem I'm facing now, is for the disconnect line in yellow line (second plot). How do I fix this?

Comment: The missing plot points are caused by the datasource returning `nil` or NAN values. You have a mismatch between the `plotData` array and the way it is being accessed in the datasource. There isn't really any need for the intermediate array in this case. The datasource can just pull the requested data directly from your data model (`self.fullVehicleData`, `self.fullTransaction`, etc.). Just be sure `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` returns the correct data count for each plot.

Comment: Hi @eric thanks for the reply. Quick question. If i use the same data for x axis for bot plots. Do i need to seperate each plot data count in ThenumberOfRecordsForPlot ? Or just return the data for x axis?

Comment: If all plots have the same number of points, you don't need to bother checking the `identifier` in `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:`. Just return the data count. Each plot will still ask for its own data, so you will have to return two sets of x-values, even if they are the same.

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, please help me one more time. I put nslog to see wether there's null value or the index is jumped, but according to the nslog data it's not skipped or returned null.

Comment: Your `plotData` contains one set of dictionaries with x-y pairs of data. No matter which plot is requesting data, you always return the same value from the `plotData` array. You're making this harder than it has to be. The datasource needs to supply x- and y-values for each index, specific to each plot. I'm having trouble following your code to figure out where the x- and y-values are stored in your model or I'd answer the question with some code to try.

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, I've updated the data, and the number of plots. Hope it will clear up your confusion. Sorry and thanks. I still have the same disconnect dot (without line)

Comment: The `index` passed to the datasource is index into the data array for the plot. You're using it for that *and* to index into your array of vehicles. You can't do that. Find the vehicle that matches the plot.identifier and then use the index to retrieve its data like you did in the first version of the datasource. Pull the data directly from the data model like in the third version.

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, thanks for you help. It works now. Now I got a problem with [graph reload]. Before calling graph reload, I did FESubView.hostedGraph  = nil; Then I also observed the count for numberofplot and the datasource already contain the new data, but the graph itself is not updating. Can you help me?

Comment: `-reloadData` tells the plots to reload their data the next time they're drawn. If you removed the graph from its hosting view, it won't be visible and has no reason to draw itself unless you explicitly tell it to draw using a method like `-imageOfLayer`.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help @Eric. How to close this thread?

Comment: Answer the question with the datasource code you came up with. Also include the code you use to build the plot data array if you still use that.